# React-web-Vector-icons types issue for typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

#34 I have installed this library in typescript to generate an error of types

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-web-vector-icons'. '/Users/apple/Documents/GitHub/ProjectAliance/node_modules/react-web-vector-icons/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try npm i --save-dev @types/react-web-vector-icons if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-web-vector-icons';

Answer (score 0):

I have add file of `#.d.ts` and have following code
it help me to solve types problem
create a new file **types.d.ts**

```js
declare module 'react-web-vector-icons' {

export default function Icon({name,size,color,font}:icon):any;
}
 

interface icon {
name: string,
size: number,
color: string,
font:string,
}
```